# Is there an equivalent to java's setFocusable() in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a `RichTextBox` that is focusable when the program begins.  After the user types in a certain number of characters, I want to stop them from changing/adding/etc anything else to the text box.

Originally I wrote this as a Java app and used `userInputBox.setFocusable(false)`, but I cannot find an equivalent way to programatically change this in C#. I am building a Windows Forms application.  I don't have any other container or object that I want the user to interact with so I cannot use `whatever.Focus()` to pull it away from my text box.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to set `ReadOnly = true` when you don't want the user to change contents?

Comment: @vcsjones Not necessarily. There could be a reason he doesn't want the control to be Focusable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `ReadOnly = true` or `Enabled = false` should do the trick, unless you really need the control to be unfocusable, in which case Oded has a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

C# has an event model that is extensively used in winforms.

You can handle the [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus) event of the control to unfocus it by calling `Focus()` on a different control.

Comment: If your application doesn't have another control to focus to, you can always put in a dummy control and make it invisible in some fashion (e.g. a Label with no text) then set focus to that.

Comment: @Abion47 - There will always be some other control. Unless all you have is a form.

Comment: The OP says in his question that there won't be "any other container or object that I want the user to interact with". I'm just adding a workaround to satisfy his situation.

Comment: Oded, at this point, I don't have anything else for the user to interact with.  I am just converting a java app to C# for the experience so it is not a complete application.  @Abion47 That is a good suggestion also but ReadOnly worked for my purposes.